# why boto3 ec2 images is too slow

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

```py
import boto3
​
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
for i in ec2.images.limit(2):
    print(i)
```

works for 50 seconds

```py
import boto3
​
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
for i in ec2.instances.limit(2):
    print(i)
```

works 2 seconds (it's ok), btw I don't need detaled information about images or instances, I need only amount of them

Answer (score 2):

By default, ALL publicly-accessible images are returned. This includes images created by other accounts.

To obtain only the AMIs (images) that are associated with your *own* account, use:

```
ec2.images.filter(Owners=['self'])
```

Comment: thank you for this information, but why limit(2) doesn't work?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does it not return two images?

Comment: I thought that limit(2) will ask server get only 2 records,at this moment server returns all records, botocode parses all these things and boto3(botocore) returuns only 2 records, I checked aws api docs, there is no way to limit server answer.

Comment: It will run a lot faster if you filter to 'self' images (as shown above).